# How to reference a static wordpress page as a relative URL for use in an iframe

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

I am using the "[jQuery iframe auto height plugin](https://github.com/house9/jquery-iframe-auto-height)" to resize an iframe to match the height of its content. This plugin only works for URLs on the same server for javascript security purposes. This becomes an issue when working with wordpress pages because they are created dynamically. I am able to link to the index page (as there is a file index.php and I can make a relative URL) but that is not the case for any other pages I create in wordpress. Is there any way to somehow send some info through $_GET to let index.php know to forward to another wordpress page?

The URL I want IS on my server, there's just not a way to make a relative URL so javascript THINKS it is from another domain. Any help would be appreciated. Tell me if I am completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha! I figured it out right after I posted this question!

All I did was use a relative URL to the index.php page and then simply added the $_GET thingy on the end which, for my static page, was ?page_id=2

So in the end my relative wordpress URL for iframe purposes was

```
[lots of folders]/index.php?page_id=2
```

Comment: Josh you are really smart, you should give yourself a pat on the back. Bravo!